# Display image depending on application theme

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I am develop an UWP app, and I am using Template 10.
I have a black image and a white image. I want when the user choose dark theme, show the white image, and when the user choose light theme show the black image, exemple:

```
if(dark theme)
{
   white image;
}
else    
{
   black image;
}
```

Comment: I dont think its a question. I think you can read the docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600513/7331395) answer works?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current RequestedTheme using `this.RequestedTheme` and then compare it with `ElementTheme.Light` or `ElementTheme.Dark`

**Method 1**

```
if (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)
    BackgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/BlackImage.png"));
else
    BackgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WhiteImage.png"));
```

**Method 2**

```
BackgroundImage.Source = (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)? new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/BlackImage.png")): new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WhiteImage.png"));
```

Comment: You may also want to take `ElementTheme.Default` into account.

Comment: @Clemens How can we identify the theme when the user uses the Default theme? Also, Default theme can be changed at run time.

Comment: No idea, I just saw that when I start my test app, that RequestedTheme is ElementTheme.Default. The app should probably have an idea what its default theme is.

Comment: @Clemens If you find any way to do it then update my answer.