# Display image depending on application theme (Dark/light theme)

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am develop an UWP app, and I am using template10. I have two images, one white and other black. I want show black image in light theme, and white image in dark theme. I have this code:

```
if (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)
    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/BlackImage.png"));
else
    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WhiteImage.png"));
```

But, when I choose light theme image dont appear! But when I choose dark theme, white image appears.

Comment: For sure this code works because I have used it in my app. Also, If you have any problem with this code then comment it on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600513/7331395) answer. Don't create a new post to say that the answer is not working.

Comment: Make sure the asset is actually where you expect it to be, did you confirm that the black image is there?

Comment: What is `this`? Is it `Application`? Or `Page`? Also are you using this in `Initialization`? or `Button` Click?

Answer (score 0):

If we do not set the [`ElementTheme.Light`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.ElementTheme) or `ElementTheme.Dark` to the [`FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_RequestedTheme), it will always return the `ElementTheme.Default`. So your Image will be set with WhiteImage, no matter the `ApplicationTheme` is `Light`.

The [`RequestedTheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_RequestedTheme) in app that can gets or sets a value that determines the light-dark preference for the overall theme of an app. It returns `ApplicationTheme` of the enumeration. It includes `Light` and `Dark`. We should be able to use `App.Current.RequestedTheme` to get the current [`ApplicationTheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationTheme) of the App.

For example:

```
var AppRequestedTheme = App.Current.RequestedTheme.ToString();
if (AppRequestedTheme == "Light")
    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/BlackImage.png"));
else
    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WhiteImage.png"));
```